# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called in the return statement

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a function

```
def nlp_func(df):
    res = {}
    #some code
    #
    #
    #
    if pos>neg :
       res[x] = "Pos"
    else:
       res[x] = "Neg"
    return pd.DataFrame(res.items(), columns=["company_names", "Value"])
```

Then I call the function as `res = nlp_func(df)`

I get the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-8195a7e5e053> in <module>()
----> 1 res = nlp_func(df)

<ipython-input-100-5ed9ac5ffc17> in nlp_func(df)
     20                 res[x] = "Neg"
     21             x = r.company_names
---> 22     return pd.DataFrame(res.items(), columns=["company_names", "Value"])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    420                                          dtype=values.dtype, copy=False)
    421             else:
--> 422                 raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
    423 
    424         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I tried finding the solution but I don't seem to find it. Please help.

Comment: How working if use `pd.DataFrame(res)` only ?

Comment: @jezrael No it's not. It gives an error that you must pass an index.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need create `DataFrame` with `keys` and `values`:

```
return pd.DataFrame({'company_names': list(res.keys()), "Value": list(res.values())})
```

Comment: Yes it did solve it. I can't upvote your answer before 5 mins. Will do after that. :)